# IntelliJ IDEA different versions compatibility

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My classmates and I are about to do a group project in Java. We want to use IntelliJ IDEA but aren’t sure about the version. My question is:
Are different versions of IntelliJ compatible? e.g. Can one of us use version 2021.2.3 and another person version 2021.2? Or one of us 2021.2 and another person 2020.2?

Answer (score 2):

As your project will probably be of `maven` or `gradle` type, you don't have to worry about this. You can even work in differents IDE (`IntelliJ`, `Eclipse` or `VS Code`).

`Maven` or `gradle` have a default project structure that most of the IDE are able to manage easily.

Or you can both just simply download the last version of [IntelliJ Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which is totaly free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think we won’t use gradle nor maven (most of us are beginners and do not have experience with these technologies). We will use Trac for project management and Subversion for version control. Do the versions of IntelliJ matter in this case?

Comment: Never heard about `Trac` before. `IntelliJ` is able to manage projects on `subversion`. I will just suggest you to download the last  `IntelliJ Community Edition` just to make sure you have the same version.

Comment: Alright, we will do that. Thank you.